# update multiple fields + rows single query

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm currently working on a CMS and I have a gallery running and the end-user can upload his foto's and they come right online.
Now I want to create an option/function that the end-user can select which photo will be put online and which won't. I found a script called update_multiple.php and that works fine, but I use MySQLi. I did some changes so it uses MySQLi, but now the script is not working and I don't know why. I don't get any error. My text is not added in my DB.

Hopefully someone can help me what I'm doing wrong.

My code;

```
<?php
ob_start();
require('../../lib/dbconnection.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM gallery";
$result=$conn->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$count=$result->num_rows;   

?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table class="OnlineImages">
....
    <?php
        /* fetch associative array */
            while ($rows = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php $id[]=$rows['id']; ?><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><input name="filename[]" type="text" id="filename" value="<?php echo $rows['filename']; ?>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="title[]" id="title" value="<?php echo $rows['title'];?>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="caption[]" id="caption" value="<?php echo $rows['caption'];?>"></td>

                <td><input type="text" name="home[]" id="home" value="<?php echo $rows['home'];?>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="photobook[]" id="photobook" value="<?php echo $rows['photobook'];?>"></td><br>
            </tr>
                <?php
        }
        ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</table>
<?php

// Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];
$caption = $_POST['caption'];
$home = $_POST['home'];
$photobook = $_POST['photobook'];
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$sql1 = " UPDATE gallery SET title='$title[$i]', caption='$caption[$i]', home='$home[$i],photobook='$photobook[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]' ";
$result1=$conn->query($sql1);
}
}
if(isset($result1)){
header("location:foto-admin.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Use var_dump($mysqli->error); after each query, otherwise we will be shooting in the dark.

Comment: I get the error: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Your variables must be identifiable as such in the string.

You need to do:

```
" UPDATE gallery SET title='{$title[$i]}', caption='{$caption[$i]}', home='{$home[$i]}',photobook='{$photobook[$i]}' WHERE id='$id[$i]' "
```

Also you were missing a ' after home.

Please be aware that this leads to sql injections and should be done with a prepared statement instead.

---

Edit:

Transmit the id, too. Change

```
<td><?php $id[]=$rows['id']; ?><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
```

To

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>" />
    <?php $id[]=$rows['id']; ?><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
```

And add

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

before

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
```

Comment: I do want to use prepared statements, but that is step further. first the basics and getting this working

Comment: I did this but that didn't help. When I transfor in from mysql to mysqli with everything else the same, I get the errors in my log;

[Wed Jun 18 06:46:40 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: id in /Users/davegreebe/Development/ClassicNails-Studio/public_html/admin/foto-admin.php on line 31, referer: http://ontwikkel.classicnails-studio.nl/admin/foto-admin.php

That is only when I submit something.

Comment: Updated my answer to accomodate this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to my knowledge few months back i have worked on this area and i have wrote a code for updating multiple rows/columns,hope this code will help u to get an idea in a different manner.

```
$group_sql  = $db->prepare("UPDATE `groups` SET `group`=? WHERE `group_id`=?;");

foreach($_POST['groups'] as $id => $group)

{

    $group_sql->execute(array($group, $id));

}
```

And multi-update:

```
$query = array();

foreach($_POST['groups'] as $id => $group)

{

    $query[] = "WHEN {$id} THEN {$db->quote($group)}";

}


$query = "

UPDATE `groups`

SET `group` = CASE `group_id`

    " . implode("\r\n", $query) . "

END

WHERE `group_id` IN (" . implode(',', array_keys($_POST['groups'])) . ");

";
```

Which will eventually generate:

```
UPDATE `groups`

SET `group` = CASE `group_id`

    WHEN 3054 THEN 'moteris savo vaikams'

    WHEN 3055 THEN 'bičių šeimoje'

END

WHERE `group_id` IN (3054,3055)


UPDATE `groups`

    SET `group` = CASE `group_id`

        WHEN 3054 THEN 'moteris savo vaikams'

        WHEN 3055 THEN 'bičių šeimoje'

    END,

    SET `description` = CASE `group_id`

        WHEN 3054 THEN 'foo'

        WHEN 3055 THEN 'bar'

    END

    WHERE `group_id` IN (3054,3055)
```